# What causes mkstemp to fail when running many simultaneous valgrind processes?

Tags: valgrind, memcheck, mkstemp

I'm doing testing of some software with valgrind. Ideally, I would like to have 20 or more instances of valgrind open at once. However, if I run more than 16 instances in parallel, I start getting messages like:

```
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_269e37a6
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_d6b675e7
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_db46c594
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_51cd683d
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_86662832
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_226a8983
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_bb94a700
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_532d4b39
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_de4a957e
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_fcc23adf
==30533== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /tmp/valgrind_proc_30533_cmdline_f41d332c
valgrind: Startup or configuration error:
valgrind:    Can't create client cmdline file in /pathtomyproject/
valgrind: Unable to start up properly.  Giving up.
```

Some of the processes (perhaps 1/3 of them) instead terminate with the error

```
==30482== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
==30482==
==30482== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==30482== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==30482==    at 0x4C6: ???
==30482==    by 0x4005D2E: open_verify (dl-load.c:1914)
==30482==    by 0x4006362: open_path (dl-load.c:2175)
==30482==    by 0x4008799: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2407)
==30482==    by 0x400CFE1: openaux (dl-deps.c:65)
==30482==    by 0x400F175: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
==30482==    by 0x400D6BD: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:258)
==30482==    by 0x400350C: dl_main (rtld.c:1826)
==30482==    by 0x4015B23: _dl_sysdep_start (dl-sysdep.c:244)
==30482==    by 0x4005364: _dl_start (rtld.c:338)
==30482==    by 0x40016B7: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==30482==    by 0x4: ???
==30482==    by 0x7FF0007C6: ???
==30482==    by 0x7FF0007DD: ???
==30482==    by 0x7FF0007E2: ???
==30482==    by 0x7FF0007E9: ???
==30482==    by 0x7FF0007EE: ???
==30482==  Address 0x4c6 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

While running these calls, no files are created in /tmp, but the user account I'm using does have read, write and execute permissions for /tmp.

I cannot find any information about this bug online, but perhaps somewhere here knows something about it?

EDIT: Some further experimentation suggests that in fact, no more than 5 processes can be run together at once.

Comment: What's the memory situation? My guess is that you're running low on free memory after 16 open instances. Add the output of free to your post.

Comment: It's a big system: 24GB of RAM, usage rarely exceeds 5% even with 20 processes at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from here:

```
// coregrind/m_libcfile.c

/* Create and open (-rw------) a tmp file name incorporating said arg.
   Returns -1 on failure, else the fd of the file.  If fullname is
   non-NULL, the file's name is written into it.  The number of bytes
   written is guaranteed not to exceed 64+strlen(part_of_name). */

Int VG_(mkstemp) ( HChar* part_of_name, /*OUT*/HChar* fullname )
{
   HChar  buf[200];
   Int    n, tries, fd;
   UInt   seed;
   SysRes sres;
   const HChar *tmpdir;

   vg_assert(part_of_name);
   n = VG_(strlen)(part_of_name);
   vg_assert(n > 0 && n < 100);

   seed = (VG_(getpid)() << 9) ^ VG_(getppid)();

   /* Determine sensible location for temporary files */
   tmpdir = VG_(tmpdir)();

   tries = 0;
   while (True) {
      if (tries++ > 10)
         return -1;
      VG_(sprintf)( buf, "%s/valgrind_%s_%08x",
                    tmpdir, part_of_name, VG_(random)( &seed ));
      if (0)
         VG_(printf)("VG_(mkstemp): trying: %s\n", buf);

      sres = VG_(open)(buf,
                       VKI_O_CREAT|VKI_O_RDWR|VKI_O_EXCL|VKI_O_TRUNC,
                       VKI_S_IRUSR|VKI_S_IWUSR);
      if (sr_isError(sres)) {
         VG_(umsg)("VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: %s\n", buf);
         continue;
      }
      /* VG_(safe_fd) doesn't return if it fails. */
      fd = VG_(safe_fd)( sr_Res(sres) );
      if (fullname)
         VG_(strcpy)( fullname, buf );
      return fd;
   }
   /* NOTREACHED */
}
```

As you can see, that code will fail if there are more than 10 processes that share the same `pid` and `ppid`. It is not clear how you are creating the 20 valgrind processes -- they should normally *not* share `pid`.

You might be able to work around the problem by either

- creating your Valgrind instances such that they do not share the same `pid`, or
- setting `TMPDIR` to a different directory for each of the Valgrind instance.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how that was happening either, but its good to know why at least!